# In SQLIte POD, DB operation main/background thread

Tags: sqlite.swift

could someone confirm that in SQLite POD https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift, DB operation used main thread or background thread. If it is used main thread then kindly provide the solution how can I use background thread for the same

My app freeze sometime when DB operation happened.